# Access Union drops combo boxes Displays -1 or 0 in datasheet view

Tags: ms-access

I had to share this as it drove me nuts for ages.

Issue I had
I required to get the same data displayed using many iif statements which looked at specific columns. The next thing the client wanted was to have different results of if statements depending on another column not associated. Meaning I needed to run a multiple query hence I had to use a UNION statement to join the queries.

The issue was when running the querys within a UNION removed the check box and showed the raw data in the database of -1 or 0. This is a qwerk of unions.
Running the queries independently returned the data with the check box.

Solution
create your union with the multiple queries.
Then create another query that queries the union and on the columns that require the combo box. Select properties, Select lookup and change display control to Check Box.

Hope this helps somebody. Drove me nuts for ages

Comment: A better approach would be to rewrite your first post to be a question and then answer your question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution create your union with the multiple queries. Then create another query that queries the union and on the columns that require the combo box. Select properties, Select lookup and change display control to Check Box.

Hope this helps somebody. Drove me nuts for ages